# Cannot resolve method 'compareTo' in 'T'

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I keep getting the error Cannot resolve method 'compareTo' in 'T' and not sure what is wrong.
The generic class T would implement Comparable and have the compareTo method. I'm trying to use the compareTo method from the generic class 'T'. I am still a beginner so any advice helps :)

```
public class Tester<T> implements Comparable<Tester>{
public int value;
private T index;

public Tester(int item1, T item2){
    value = item1;
    index = item2;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Tester o) {
    return this.index.compareTo(o.index);
}
```

I've also tried changing the function like this:

```
public class Tester<T> implements Comparable<T> {
public int value;
private T index;

public Tester(int item, T item2){
    value = item;
    index = item2;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(T o) {
    return this.index.compareTo(o);
}
```

Also tried this:

```
public class Tester<T> implements Comparable {
public int value;
public T index;

public Tester(int item, T item2){
    value = item;
    index = item2;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Ticket b = (Ticket)o;
    return this.index.compareTo(b.index);
}
```

Comment: `T` needs to implement `Comparable`.

Comment: I am aware of that

Comment: Well, that's the answer to the question ..

Comment: I think inside the compareTo method you should have custom logic and there you can't use compareTo method as it's not available in Object class

Comment: Just as a hint: All the compiler knows about `T` is .. `<T>`.

Comment: You need to constrain `T` to implement `Comparable`, e.g. `class Tester<T extends Comparable<T>>`

Comment: I get an error saying class Tester cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (Tester is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: Well that's a different error... unfortunately we don't really know what you're trying to achieve, which makes it quite hard to help you. It's not even clear whether it really should implement `Comparable<T>`, or `Comparable<Tester<T>>`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but I somehow managed to fix the issue by trying:                          `public class Tester<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Tester>`